# How to clear Powershell Cache

Tags: windows, powershell, office365

I am currently running into an issue that when I run a script via PowerShell, it attempts to run the script but keeps failing because of credentials are incorrect. I recently changed my password however PowerShell isn't prompting me to enter my new ones.

Is there a way to have PowerShell clear my cached creds so I can enter my new one?

Comment: Powershell uses your current logged in credentials. Log off your computer and log in again while connected to the domain.

Comment: This is not a PowerShell but a general Windows issue. To complement @Scepticalist comment, make sure that you are connected to the domain while logging on. If it doesn't concern your Windows credentials, but e.g. some internet credentials, check the [credential manager](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/accessing-credential-manager-1b5c916a-6a16-889f-8581-fc16e8165ac0)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Thank you everyone for your assistance. My issue was resolved when I typed the following command.

```
save-creds
```

It prompted me to enter my credentials for the script

Comment: What is this cmdlet? My workstation doesn't have this nor can I find it documented anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You need to either log out or lock your workstation and unlock it with `Windows_Key + L`.

As mentioned in the comments, this is a Windows issue, and is just what you need to do when rotating your credentials while logged in. Re-authenticating will refresh your cached principal, and locking/unlocking is sufficient enough in most cases as this forces you to re-authenticate with current credentials.

> Note: If you changed your password using `Ctrl+Alt+Del > Change Password`, you shouldn't need to log out and in again, but if you find this is required I would recommend asking on [Super User](https://superuser.com) or [Server Fault](http://Server%20Fault) about this behavior.

Comment: I'm not sure why this was downvoted because it's not incorrect. I won't say there isn't any cmdlet that will refresh your current logged in principal as this may technically be possible with the Win32 API, but I'm not aware of any built into PowerShell.